# Persistence using Typescript

Tags: json, node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I'm currently working in a project using Electron (basically nodejs with chromium) plus Angular2

Is there any way to save a typescript object in a file?

Currently, I'm saving objects in a json file. The problem is that all object methods are lost

Should I try to save the __proto__ variable?

Should I use a framework or a special database engine?

Today I'm reading the object from a the json file and parsing it using JSON.parse. Then I reassign all the properties in a new object, which is not scalable

Any suggestion is welcome

Thanks in advance. José

Comment: I think any persistence framework would require you to specify serialization patterns of some sort. I am not aware of any ORM for nodejs but if I had to do it myself, I'd start with defining a serialization protocol.

Comment: It all depends on what the specific needs of the project are. I've done it with an ad-hoc system that supports a finite set of types. The serialization records the type as a number, then the parameters that must be passed to the constructor. The deserializer converts the type number to a constructor and then instantiates an object by passing the arguments to the constructor. This has worked very well for years. The project for which it was designed would not benefit from something more sophisticated. Other projects would have other needs that would make this solution inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP!

I just find this library that, apparently, solve the problem

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serializer.ts

> So what to do? How to have in users array of User objects instead of
>   plain javascript objects? Solution is to create new instances of User
>   object and manually copy all properties to new objects.
>
> Alternatives? Yes, you can use this library. Purpose of this library
>   is to help you to map you plain javascript objects to the instances of
>   classes you have created.

I'll give a shot and feedback. Bests

Comment: Hi @sct999. Yes, it worked fine. But check other alternatives to serialize if you have time.
What I finally did in that opportunity to solve that specific issue was a dirty trick: I saved the object in a text file using JSON.stringify(object) and then JSON.parse() to load it
I read somewhere that it was the fastest way to do it, but can't remember the reference, I'm sorry.
Bests

Answer (score 1):

You can export variables as json like:

**myJsons.ts**:

```
export var myVar = {
  name: "John"
}
```

and use them inside your ts files like:

**myComponent.ts**:

```
import {myVar} from '../path-to-myJsons'

this.myJson = myVar;
this.name = this.myJson.name;
```

Comment: I think his issue is that private members disappear - any of them.

Comment: @Sebas oh then I misunderstood the issue. OP can you clarify this?

Comment: The issue is that all class "meta" (public and private methods) are lost when I save a object into a file.
I need to find a way to save the entire object in a file (json, text, binary... I don't care).
May be, as @Louis wrote, object serialization is the solution